# Probabilistic solution to the Dirichlet problem with Dynkin formula

Tags: brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, boundary-value-problem, stopping-times

I have two small questions to the probabilistic solution to the Dirichlet problem using Dynkin's formula. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhr6B.png) is how we introduced it and I marked the two equalities I'm referring to.

1. Why is $\int_0^{\infty} P_x(\tau_G > t) dt \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_x(\tau_G >n)$?
2. How do we use the tower property for the second equation? $P_x(\tau_G > n-1, \tau_G(n-1)>n)=E_x[1_{\{\tau_G>n-1\}}P_x(\tau_G(n-1)>n)|\mathcal{F}_n-1)]$

Answer (score 0):

1. This follows from
   $$
   \int_0^{\infty} P_x(\tau_G>t)dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_n^{n+1}P_x(\tau_G>t)dt\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_x(\tau_G>n)\int_n^{n+1}dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_x(\tau_G>n),
   $$
   using the fact that $t\mapsto P_x(\tau_G>t)$ is nonincreasing.
2. We have
   \begin{align}
   P_x(\tau_G>n-1,\tau_G(n-1)>n)&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}(\tau_G>n-1)\mathbf{1}(\tau_G(n-1)>n)]\\
   &=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}(\tau_G>n-1)\mathbf{1}(\tau_G(n-1)>n)\vert \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]]\\
   &=\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}(\tau_G>n-1)\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}(\tau_G(n-1)>n)\vert \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]]\\
   &=\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}(\tau_G>n-1)\Pr(\tau_G(n-1)>n\vert \mathcal{F}_{n-1})],
   \end{align}
   where the second equality is the tower property and the third is from $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$-measurability of the first indicator.

Comment: I still I have one more question, why the following equation holds:
$P_y(\tau_G \leq 1) \geq P_y (B_1 \in U_1(y+z)) = P_0(B_1 \in U_1(z)) > 0$.
 
1.) In the fist inequality, I am thinking that the probability that the first exit time $\tau_G$ is smaller or equal to $1$ must be greater or equal to the probability of the Brownian motion being at time $1$ in the complement of the set. Since we are asking just for this only probabilty, which is also included in $P_y(\tau_g \leq 1)$. Right?

Comment: 2.) My last question reverse to the last equality, is it because of the Stationarity of the Brownian motion? 

3.) And furthermore, is the probability at the end positive because of the recurrence of the brownian motion?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes, a Brownian motion started at an arbitrary point has the same law as a motion started at the origin, appropriately translated. 3) $B_1$ is distributed like a normal random variable, which has positive density everywhere so has nonzero probability of being in any arbitrary open set.